# ClassNotFoundException on TapestryFilter with Tynamo archetype

Tags: maven, jetty, tapestry, tynamo

I'm setting up a new project with tynamo-archetype based on tynamo and Tapestry (lets call it division), and I'm facing an issue when running jetty in order to test it.

I generated id with `mvn archetype:generate` on tynamo catalog.

### Error

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building division-t5-tynamo - My Tynamo project
[INFO]    task-segment: [jetty:run]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Preparing jetty:run
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 6 resources
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [resources:testResources {execution: default-testResources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] [compiler:testCompile {execution: default-testCompile}]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [jetty:run {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] Configuring Jetty for project: division-t5-tynamo - My Tynamo project
[INFO] webAppSourceDirectory D:\ecommerce\workspaces\division\division-t5-tynamo\src\main\webapp does not exist. Defaulting to D:\ecommerce\workspaces\division\division-t5-
tynamo\src\main\webapp
[INFO] Reload Mechanic: automatic
[INFO] Classes = D:\ecommerce\workspaces\division\division-t5-tynamo\target\classes
[INFO] Context path = /
[INFO] Tmp directory = D:\ecommerce\workspaces\division\division-t5-tynamo\target\tmp
[INFO] Web defaults = org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
[INFO] Web overrides =  none
[INFO] web.xml file = file:/D:/ecommerce/workspaces/division/division-t5-tynamo/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
[INFO] Webapp directory = D:\ecommerce\workspaces\division\division-t5-tynamo\src\main\webapp
2012-10-08 12:39:02.681:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-7.6.0.v20120127
2012-10-08 12:39:02.915:INFO:oejpw.PlusConfiguration:No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one, please configure one.
2012-10-08 12:39:03.087:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.m.j.p.JettyWebAppContext{/,file:/D:/ecommerce/workspaces/division/division-t5-tynamo/src/main/webapp/},fil
e:/D:/ecommerce/workspaces/division/division-t5-tynamo/src/main/webapp/
2012-10-08 12:39:03.102:WARN:oejs.Holder:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter
```

### pom.xml

My only customization were to remove the following lines ...

```xml
<contextPath>/${project.artifactId}</contextPath>
```

Here the full pom

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>fr.company.division</groupId>
    <artifactId>division-t5-tynamo</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>4.9.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>division-t5-tynamo - My Tynamo project</name>
    <url>http://tynamo.org/</url>

<!--  -->

    <properties>
        <tynamo-version>0.3.0</tynamo-version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>division-t5-tynamo</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.11</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <optimize>true</optimize>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Run the application using "mvn jetty:run" -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.6.0.v20120127</version>
                <configuration>
                    <contextPath>/${project.artifactId}</contextPath>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <name>tapestry.execution-mode</name>
                            <value>development</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- This changes the WAR file packaging so that what would normally go into WEB-INF/classes
                 is instead packaged as WEB-INF/lib/division-t5-tynamo.jar. This is necessary for Tapestry
                 to be able to search for page and component classes at startup. Only
                 certain application servers require this configuration, please see the documentation
                 at the Tapestry 5 project page (http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry5/).
             -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1-beta-1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- This gets the plugin to clean up the cobertura.ser file left
        in the root directory. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>clean</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clean</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <!-- Adds a report detailing the components, mixins and base classes defined by this module. -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId>
                <artifactId>tapestry-component-report</artifactId>
                <version>5.2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <rootPackage>fr.company.division</rootPackage>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <dependencyDetailsEnabled>false</dependencyDetailsEnabled>
                    <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.tynamo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tapestry-model-hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>${tynamo-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.tynamo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tapestry-model-test</artifactId>
            <version>${tynamo-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.tynamo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tapestry-model-web</artifactId>
            <version>${tynamo-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.tynamo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tapestry-routing</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.165</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <!--
    IMPORTANT NOTE:

    Configuring repositories is against Maven best practices. If you have
    a repository manager in use, remove this section and configure your
    repository manager to proxy these repositories instead.
    -->
    <repositories>
        <!-- Don't use snapshots unless absolutely necessary -->
        <repository>
            <id>codehaus-nexus-snapshots</id>
            <name>Codehaus Nexus Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://nexus.codehaus.org/content/groups/snapshots-group/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>repository.jboss.org</id>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

        <!--
            little hack to disable java.net repositories because they are not working
            and they corrupt your local repo.
        -->
        <repository>
            <id>maven-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <url>https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>java.net</id>
            <url>https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

    </repositories>

</project>
```

### Web.xml

Tapestry filter is well declared in web.xml, and java package seems to match properties :

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE web-app
            PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
            "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
    <web-app>

        <display-name>division-t5-tynamo</display-name>

        <context-param>
            <!-- The only significant configuration for Tapestry 5, this informs Tapestry
                of where to look for pages, components, mixins and entities. -->
            <param-name>tapestry.app-package</param-name>
            <param-value>fr.company.division</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <!--
            Specify some additional Modules for two different execution
            modes: development and qa.
            Remember that the default execution mode is production
            -->
        <context-param>
            <param-name>tapestry.development-modules</param-name>
            <param-value>
                fr.company.division.services.DevelopmentModule
            </param-value>
        </context-param>
        <context-param>
            <param-name>tapestry.qa-modules</param-name>
            <param-value>
                fr.company.division.services.QaModule
            </param-value>
        </context-param>
        <filter>
            <filter-name>app</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter</filter-class>
        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>app</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>

        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>

    </web-app>
```

I can't figure out what's the problem. It's not my first Tapestry project, but this the first time I use tynamo ...

Comment: Everything looks good. I've tried your exact same configuration (groupId, artifactId and package) without any problems. The only difference is that I'm on MacOSX and it looks like you are using MS Windows. The / contextPath shouldn't be an issue either. Can you try with a different jetty version? Maybe using the same version that any other Tapestry project you have already working. You can try with the 6.1.16 version Tapestry uses in its archetype: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tapestry/tapestry5/trunk/quickstart/filtered/archetype-resources/pom.xml

Comment: I tried and it works quite well with <version>8.1.2.v20120308</version> :). You may post your comment as an answer, and I will accept it :). Thanks a lot

Comment: Indeed, it's not the first time I'm facing an issue with Jetty 7x, and not with version 6 or 8 ... strange ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks good. I've tried your exact same configuration (groupId, artifactId and package) without any problems. The only difference is that I'm on MacOSX and it looks like you are using MS Windows. The / *contextPath* shouldn't be an issue either. 
Can you try with a different jetty version? 
Maybe using the same version that any other Tapestry project you have already working. 
You can try with the 6.1.16 version Tapestry uses in its archetype: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tapestry/tapestry5/trunk/quickstart/filtered/archetype-resources/pom.xml